# HTML/JavaScript - back to previous popup window

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have a page with a link to a popup window, within this popup window is a link to another popup window. When I submit in the second popup window it goes back to the original web page. How can I go back to the previous popup window.

I tried `history.go(-1)` but this brought me back to the original webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.opener will give you the opening source.

Therefore you could do something like:

`window.opener.focus();` to bring that popup forward.